# Suppose that for all $i \le k$, one knows a polynomial $f_i$ such that $f_i(x) = x^i$, calculate $f_{k+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, summation, binomial-theorem

This is a problem I have been stuck with for 3-4 days, I've searched everywhere, did all I could, and still couldn't find the answer.

First of all this problem is a part of a problem set, I've solved all of them and this question remains unsolved, here is the problem set because it may help understanding the problem

1. If $f(x)$ is a non-zero problem of degree d, then show that $f(x) - f(x-1)$ gives us a problem with a degree d - 1
2. If $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ then show that $f(x) - f(x-1) = g(x) - g(x-1) + h(x) - h(x-1)$
3. Use the binomial theorem to calculate $\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} - \frac{{(x-1)}^{k+1}}{k+1}$

I've solved them all, the solution to the last problem is
$$\sum_{p=0}^{k} \frac{1}{p+1} \binom{k}{p} \cdot x^{k-p} \cdot \left(-1\right)^{p}$$

Okay now the problem that I couldn't solve is:

> Suppose that for all $i \le k$, one knows a polynomial $f_i$ such that $f_i(x) = x^i$. The last problem gave us $f_i$ for $i = 0, 1,2, 3$ and $4$. Combine your work on this problem in order to show you how to calculate $f_{k+1}$

So here are my solving attempts
Let's try getting x^0 which is 1, okay? Since f(x) - f(x-1) give us a polynomial of degree (d - 1) and we want d - 1 to be 0, therefore d must be 1

$$f(x) = ax + b$$
$$f(x-1) = ax - a + b$$
Subtracting we get $a$, we need $a$ to equal $x^0$ and $x^0 = 1$ so $a = 1$ so
$$f_0 = x + b $$ 
If we cancel $b$, we get $x$ which equals $\sum_{i=0}^x i^0$

Now let's try  getting $x$, the degree must be $2$ so
$$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$
$$f(x-1) = ax^2 - 2ax + a + bx - b + c$$
Subtracting we get $$2ax + a- b$$

And this should be equal $x$, so how do we make it equal $x$? first let's get rid of the constant by setting $a = b$

$$2ax$$

Then the obvious next move is to make $a = 0.5$ to make it equal $x$
So $a = 0.5$ and $b = a = 0.5$ so the polynomial is
$\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x}{2} + c$ ($c$ is any constant)
Let's play with this a bit to get

$$f_1 = \frac{x(x+1)}{2} + c$$ 
Sounds familiar, right? it is a famous summation, by removing $c$ we get
$\sum_{i=0}^x i$

Now let's try getting $x^2$ so the degree must be $3$

$$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$
$$f(x-1) = ax^3 - 3ax^2 + 3ax - a + bx^2 - 2bx + b + cx - c + d$$
Subtracting we get
$$3ax^2 - 3ax + a + 2bx - b + c = 3ax^2 + (2b - 3a)x + a 
+ c - b$$ 
And this should be equal to $x^2$, mhm, so how do we start?

Let's eliminate the constants by setting $b = a + c$
Then eliminate $x^1$ by setting $2b = 3a$
Then set the coefficient of $x^2$ to $1$ by setting $a = \frac{1}{3}$
Consequently $b = 0.5$ and $c = 0.5 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$
So we have our polynomial
$$f_2 = \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x}{6} + d$$
Sounds similiar too, by cancelling $d$, this is equal to the famous
$\sum_{i=0}^x i^2$

Now let's get $x^3$ (tired yet? this will be the last one)

$$f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$$
$$f(x-1) = ax^4 - 4ax^3 + 6ax^2 + 4ax + a + bx^3 - 3bx^2 + 3bx - b + cx^2 - 2cx + c + dx - d + e$$
by Subtracting we get,
$$4ax^3 + (3b - 6a)x^2 + (4a - 3b + 2c) + (b + d - (a + c))$$
How to make the above an x^3? I won't go through the steps this time but it will be $a = 0.25$, $b = 0.5$, $c = 0.25$ and $d = 0$
So the polynomial would be
$$f_3 = \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^3}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4}$$
Which is you know, equal to $\sum_{i=0}^x i^3$

Okay all of this was fun, we found out how to get the summation of successive $x$, $x^2$ , $x^3$. And we could find out how to get the summation of $x^k$ easily (by finding $f_k$) if $k$ was known, but if $k$ wasn't known, how do I find $f_k$?

This is the part that I couldn't solve in the question

Oh yeah and this question suggests that there is some relation between it and the previous one($\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} - \frac{{(x-1)}^{k+1}}{k+1}$), Ok I tried plugging $i = 0, i = 1, i = 2, i = 3$ and $i = 4$. Here are the results which are pretty weird and I don't see any relation to this problem.

$i = 0 : 1$

$i = 1 : x - 0.5$

$i = 2 : x^2 - x + \frac{1}{3}$

$i = 3 : x^3 - 1.5x^2 + x - 0.25$

$i = 4 : x^4 - 2x^3 + 2x^2 - x + 0.2$

Ok so these are my solving attempts, so how do I solve this problem?

Comment: ”The last problem gave us $f_i$ for i=0,1,2,3 and 4" : I don't understand. $f_i$ is not the polynomial $x^i$ given just before ?

Comment: @paf I think you have a problem with the problem statement? same here, but I didn't invent the problem, I had it on a textbook

Comment: What is the context of the problem set?

Comment: Trying to find a general formula for the summation of sucessive i, i^2, i^3, etc...

Comment: So it gave me a couple of summation formulae to prove (sucessive i, i^2, i^3) and then it says "Although it is easy enough to verify by induction that each of the previous formulas hold, it is not so obvious how one came up with the formula to verify in the first place. This exercise will give you an idea of how to do it."